# call a method several times before getting response from volley

Tags: android, android-volley

I am getting base 64 encoded format image string from server: `hNiCHLy9Ax3gKMv81IBJ1457175735`.So I downloaded and use that imagestring to covert that into bitmap.

Now My only problem is, I have to call the loadImage(base64Image) method nearly eight times inside that for loop.But it is not calling the method single time because of asynchronous volley, it directly get into volley get response.

Because of that I can't save values to arraylist.that's why I am getting arrayIndexOutOfBoundException.

Below I have posted the logcat and codes relevant to this issue:

**Logcat:** (Edited)

```
03-22 08:39:43.795 30971-30971/com.android.burblr E/urlAva: http://example.com/api/v1/file=3UulRIaeyVTpKYfkA5og1458204300
03-22 08:39:43.795 30971-30971/com.android.burblr E/base64Image: 3UulRIaeyVTpKYfkA5og1458204300
03-22 08:39:43.795 30971-30971/com.android.burblr E/Calling BitMAp....: 3UulRIaeyVTpKYfkA5og1458204300
03-22 08:39:43.795 30971-30971/com.android.burblr E/Calling try: Calling try
03-22 08:39:43.795 30971-30971/com.android.burblr E/getAvaArrStr: cUZdHWN9KzYMtmusvqnE1446770662
03-22 08:39:43.795 30971-30971/com.android.burblr E/urlAva: http://example.com/api/v1/file=cUZdHWN9KzYMtmusvqnE1446770662
03-22 08:39:43.795 30971-30971/com.android.burblr E/base64Image: cUZdHWN9KzYMtmusvqnE1446770662
03-22 08:39:43.795 30971-30971/com.android.burblr E/Calling BitMAp....: cUZdHWN9KzYMtmusvqnE1446770662
03-22 08:39:43.795 30971-30971/com.android.burblr E/Calling try: Calling try
03-22 08:39:43.805 30971-30971/com.android.burblr D/Volley: [1] DiskBasedCache.remove: Could not delete cache entry for key=http://example.com/api/v1/file=cUZdHWN9KzYMtmusvqnE1446770662, filename=993968043-2098536571
03-22 08:39:43.827 30971-31011/com.android.burblr W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-22 08:39:43.827 30971-31011/com.android.burblr W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xe195f3c0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
03-22 08:39:44.088 30971-30971/com.android.burblr E/came: came
03-22 08:39:44.088 30971-30971/com.android.burblr E/arrBitMap: []
```

**CardFragment.java:**

```
  void hitImageApi(){

        final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), null, null);
        ProgressBar spinner = new android.widget.ProgressBar( getActivity(),null,android.R.attr.progressBarStyle);
        spinner.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#009689"), android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
        dialog.setContentView(spinner);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();



        for (int i=0; i < alAvaArr.size(); i++){

             getAvaArrStr = alAvaArr.get(i);

            Log.e("getAvaArrStr",""+getAvaArrStr);


            urlAva = BurblrUtils.BR_AVATAR_IMAGE + "file=" +getAvaArrStr ;

            Log.e("urlAva", urlAva);

            base64Image = getAvaArrStr;

            Log.e("base64Image", "" + base64Image);

            loadImage(base64Image);


            requestAva = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, urlAva, new Response.Listener<String>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    if(response != null && !response.startsWith("<HTML>")){
                        Log.e("ResponseAvatar", response);
                        dialog.dismiss();

                        try {

                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Running ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            getSwipeImage();

                            myAppAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }

                    }else{
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    if(error != null){
                        Log.e("error", error.toString());
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }

                }
            }){
                @Override
                protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                    Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    params.put("file", getAvaArrStr );

                    Log.e("paramsImg", ""+params);

                    return params;
                }

                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                    return params;
                }
            };

        }

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
        queue.add(requestAva);
        queue.getCache().remove(urlAva);

    }





      void loadImage(String src) {

     Log.e("Calling BitMAp....", "" + src);


     try {

         Log.e("Calling try", "Calling try");
         URL url = new URL(src);

         Log.e("url", ""+url);

         HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
         connection.setDoInput(true);
         connection.connect();
         InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
         Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);

         Log.e("myBitmap", ""+myBitmap);

         bitMapToString(myBitmap);

     } catch (IOException e) {
         // Log exception
         Log.e("IOError", ""+e);
     }

}

    public String bitMapToString(Bitmap bitmap){


        ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new  ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100, baos);
        byte [] b=baos.toByteArray();
        String temp=Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);

        Log.e("temp", ""+temp);

        arrBitMap.add(temp);

        return temp;
    }
```

I need to call volley GET response after called  `loadImage(base64Image)` method eight times.any suggestion

Comment: Your question is little confusing. What are you exactly trying to do? Do you need to call requestAva = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, urlAva, new Response.Listener<String>() after the loadImage() method is called 8 times? If you know the number of times you want to call your loadImage method then simply keep a track of that number in onresponse method and if that number is equal to 8 (or whatever) , try to notify the adapter then.

Comment: @ManshaChuttani I dont know that no.of times.I had dynacmically getting in arraylist size.I need to call loadImage() method several times before calling to onresponse method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically u want to avoid all the work you are doing in onResponse till the load image is called the number of times equal to the size of alAvaArr array. So, you can declare a global int variable up and increment it each time in onResponse. Now check in on response that the value of this variable is equal to the size of alAvaArr array or not. If not, do nothing else whatever you wana do in OnResponse:

```
                    dialog.dismiss();

                    try {

                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Running ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        getSwipeImage();

                        myAppAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
```

Comment: do you know why this Log.e("myBitmap", ""+myBitmap); is not calling.But i can enter into  Log.e("Calling BitMAp....", "");

Comment: There must be some error in your try catch block. You are only printing IOException. Definitely because of some exception , Log.e("myBitmap", ""+myBitmap); is not reachable.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion and answer

Comment: I am glad i could help. Thanks for accepting the answer :)